# Use TeamCity to FTP Upload result of previous Maven Build

Tags: teamcity

I'm using TeamCity to build a Java project with Maven, and there's two Build Steps:

1. Get code from bitbucket with git, build with Maven, then upload it to jfrog with Maven.
2. FTP upload to Azure.

The problem I'm running into the following log:

> [Step 2/2] Starting upload via FTP to ftp://....
>   [Step 2/2] Uploaded [0] files for [] pattern

I think I need to put something in the "Paths to sources:" field, but I don't know what.  I've tried some random file paths, and I tried `dir/**/*.war`, but I basically have no idea what to put in here.

I've read through the following pages, and it comes back to the same line in the Teamcity UI and [FTP Upload doc page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/FTP+Upload):

> Specify the deployment sources as a newline- or comma-separated list of paths to files/diretories to be deployed. Ant-style wildcards like dir/**/*.zip and target directories like *.zip => winFiles,unix/distro.tgz => linuxFiles, where winFiles and linuxFiles are target directories, are supported.

I just have no idea where the first step is putting these artifacts locally.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer while writing the question and looking at one of the comments from this other answer, [TeamCity local artifact path pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39295683/teamcity-local-artifacts-path-pattern), where someone made the following comment:

> Is the last number not the `%system.build.number%`?

In the TeamCity editor, I entered the character `%`, and I read through the autofill options until I found a `%..%` pattern that might work for me.

I tried it, and I ended up using the following pattern:

```
%teamcity.agent.home.dir%/**/webapp/target/*.war
```